# Wildfly (8.2.final): How to read a classpath resource?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1, wildfly-8, java-ee-7

I have a property file in the classpath of my application.

src/main/resources/default.properties

In an ejb, it has singleton and startup annotations, I try to read the file as following

```
Thread.currentThead().getContextLoader().getResource("default.properties");
```

This doesn't work. Works in Glassfish though.

Is there any way to read classpath resource in wildfly?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution of this? I am facing some weird problem. I am deploying ear in Wildfly but for some of the archives I am not able to read files from classpath resource.

Comment: Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The call

```
Thread.currentThead().getContextLoader().getResource("default.properties");
```

Doesn't work, but the following works.

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread ().getContextClassLoader ()
                .getResourceAsStream ( "default.properties" );
```

I don't know why it is so, but may be this will help.